# Redirect , POST and Flashdata issue in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation, message

i am developing an application where i need some suggestions. Here is the detail of the problem.

```
public function form()
{
    $this->load->helper('inflector');
    $id =   $this->uri->segment(3,0); 

    if($data = $this->input->post()){
        $result =   $this->form_validation->run();
        if($result){
            if($id > 0){
              // here update code
            }else{
                $this->mymodel->insert($data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','The page has been added successfully.');
                $this->redirect =   "mycontroller/index";
                $this->view     =   FALSE;
            }
        }else{
            //$this->call_post($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','The Red fields are required');
            $this->view     =   FALSE;
            $this->redirect =   "mycontroller/form/$id";
        }
    }else{

        $row    =   $this->mymodel->fetch_row($id);
        $this->data[]=  $row;
    }
}


public function _remap($method, $parameters)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method))
    {
        $return =   call_user_func_array(array($this, $method),$parameters);
    }else{
        show_404();
    }

    if(strlen($this->view) > 0)
    {
        $this->template->build('default',array());

    }else{
        redirect($this->redirect);
    }   
}
```

Here you can see how i am trying to reload the page on failed validation. 
Now the problem is that i have to display the flash data on the view form which is only available after redirect and i need to display the validation errors to which are not being displayed on redirect due to the loss of post variable. If i dont use redirect then cant display flashdata but only validation errors. I want both of the functionalities togather. I have tried even creating POSt again like this

```
public function call_post($data)
{
    foreach($data as $key => $row){
        $_POST[$key]    =   $row;
    }   
}
```

Which i commented out in the formmethod.How can i achieve this.

Comment: I m not sure i got you right but why you need to redirect at the first place, you can just load the view and you still have the same URL Controller/form/$id if validation failed, update what you can redirect if success with flash message as success but as long it fails no redirection, update me with your reply

Comment: youare right but on redirect i am loosing post data it is not availabe to diplsay error messages

Comment: Ahmed's logic is the way to go, instead of doing a redirect, you want to simply load the current view again. Only redirect when the validation is successful.

Comment: exactly instead of saving errors in session either flash or normal session, you may just load the view and let the form_errors() handle the rest, you don't need to redirect when you have errors only load the view again and redirect after success you will only have a success message to save in flash data with is acceptable practice

Comment: hi have you tried my code.

Comment: Well guys thanks for your reply but i have a design where it is necessary to display a flash message because my form has many tabs and i have t tell the user there are other validation errors in the tabs that are not currently active. All the suggestions including of @umerfarooq i have been using but i need both togather

Comment: @raheel - You can still do that without redirecting. Just add something like `if(validation_errors()){ show generic "there are errors" message }` to your view. It will be true when there are any errors on the form, no matter which tab they are in.

Comment: error messages can be displayed easily i know but the flash message cant be

Comment: How about adding the validation error messages in your flash data?

Comment: Well this is a good suggestion let me try it

Comment: @raheelshan Just posted a more descriptive answer below. Let me know if it works, OK? I personally haven't tried it before. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a thought.

I think you can add the validation error messages into the flash data. Something like this should work:

> $this->session->set_flashdata('validation_error_messages',validation_errors());

Notice the call to the validation_errors function. This is a bit unconventional, but I think it should work. Just make sure that the code are executed after the statement `$this->form_validation->run();` to make sure the validation error messages are produced by the Form Validation library.

Comment: Thank you for suggestioni have alos found a library which works as you suggest here it is https://github.com/eddmann/ci-flash

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for link. That's one handy library. :)

Answer (score 0):

well i have little different approach hope will help you here it is

```
   mycontroller extend CI_Controller{

      function _remap($method,$params){
         switch($method){
            case 'form':
                   $this->form($params);
            break;
            default:
                    $this->index();
            break;
         }
      }

      function form(){
          $this->load->helper('inflector');
          $id =   $this->uri->segment(3,0); 

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Named','required|trim');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email|trim');

          // if validation fails and also for first time form called
          if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
                   $this->template->build('default',array());
           }
           else{ // validation passed
               $this->save($id)
           }

      }

       function save($id = 0){
           $data = $this->input->post();
          if($id == 0){
            $this->mymodel->insert($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','The page has been added successfully.');
            $this->redirect =   "mycontroller/index";
            $this->view     =   FALSE;
        }else{
            // update the field
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','The Red fields are required');
        }

        redirect("mycontroller/index");

       }

   }
```

your form/default view should be like this

```
<?
    if(validation_errors())
      echo validation_errors();
    elseif($this->session->flashdata('message'))
       echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); 

    echo form_open(uri_string());// post data to same url
    echo form_input('name',set_value('name'));
     echo form_input('email',set_value('email'));
     echo form_submit('submit');
     echo form_close();
```

try it if you face any problem post here.